# Combine custom authentication filter with spring-security-kerberos

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-kerberos

I'm using spring-security-kerberos to authenticate the remote users - this works well. The problem that I have is that sometimes users do not have the kerberos ticket in place and I need to use another form of authentication. I've wrote my own Authentication Provider (`myCusomAuthenticationProvider`) for this purpose. This custom provider should ask the user for BASIC authentication and uses several LDAP servers to authenticate the user based on username and password.

The problem that I see is that my custom authentication manager always gets KerberosServiceRequestToken as the authentication token and I don't manage to get UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. How can I make the server return both "Negotiate" and "Basic" methods to the browser and have my own provider handle the basic authentication?

I've found a way to do it with some tweaks to the spring-security-kerberos code but I'm trying to find a better way to do this.

web.xml: http://pastebin.com/embed.php?i=ZidnBMwZ

root-context-with-krb.xml: http://pastebin.com/c8vfUZfV

Comment: did 0x5a4d answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will help you [Optional kerberos authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066184/optional-kerberos-authentication/26300751#26300751)

And if you're need more custom, then extends *KerberosAuthenticationProvider* by your class *MyCustomAuthenticationProvider* and paste it to class attribute:

```xml
<bean id="kerberosAuthenticationProvider" class="com.test.MyCustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="kerberosClient">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosClient">
            <property name="debug" value="${krb.debug}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="dummyUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```